# Rails: Factory Girl failing to sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Just getting started with factory girl, and I've come across a problem with sequencing: Specifically, it doesn't increment. I've tried changing the database type, updating from factory_girl 1.3.2 to 2.0.0.beta1 (And factory_girl_rails from 1.0 to 1.1.0.beta1), tried recreating the database, but same problem - the sequence won't increment and I get a validation error after the first time I insert a unique field.

Any assistance much appreciated. Code & trace stack below:

/spec/models/user.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do   describe "test user factory is correct" do
    user = Factory(:user)

    it "should have an email ending in example.com" do
      #user.email.should match "test2@example.com"
    end

    it "should have a password of foobar" do
      user.password.should == 'foobar'
    end

    it "should have a password confirmation field of foobar" do
      user.password_confirmation.should == 'foobar'
    end
    end

end
```

/spec/factories/user.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| puts "Email ##{n}"; "factory_#{n}@example.com" }
    f.password 'foobar'
    f.password_confirmation { |p| p.password }
end
```

Trace:

```
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:49:in `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:242:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:242:in `save!'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy/create.rb:6:in `result'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:327:in `run'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:270:in `create'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:301:in `default_strategy'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl.rb:20:in `Factory'
    from /Users/john/Websites/Rails/InDevelopment/fastermanager/spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:131:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:131:in `subclass'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:118:in `describe'
    from /Users/john/Websites/Rails/InDevelopment/fastermanager/spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:131:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:131:in `subclass'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:118:in `describe'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/object.rb:6:in `describe'
    from /Users/john/Websites/Rails/InDevelopment/fastermanager/spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `map'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:388:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:44:in `run'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Why do you have two statements inside this block? f.sequence(:email) { |n| puts "Email ##{n}"; "factory_#{n}@example.com" }

Comment: Have you tried doing `tail -f log/test.log` while this runs?

Comment: Are you using autotest? Also, what database cleaning strategy are you using to clean out your test db between runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue isn't with factory girl.  When instantiating "user" you need to do it from inside a before block so that a new user gets created for each test being run.  The user variable should also be an instance variable (i.e. prefixed with @)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do   

  describe "test user factory is correct" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    it "should have an email ending in example.com" do
      @user.email.should match "test2@example.com"
    end

    it "should have a password of foobar" do
      @user.password.should == 'foobar'
    end

    it "should have a password confirmation field of foobar" do
      @user.password_confirmation.should == 'foobar'
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 7):

With the [latest syntax](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md):

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :email { |n| "test#{n}@email.com" }

  factory :user do
    name          "John Doe"
    email         { FactoryGirl.generate(:email) }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the sequence separately?  Here's an excerpt from one of my factory files:

```
Factory.sequence(:email)       {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.name                  "John Doe"
  f.email                 { Factory.next :email }
end
```

Comment: (I know FG supports defining sequences inline in the factory, but it'd be good to see if your issue is specific to the inline syntax, or applies to sequences defined with the older syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that happens, but here are a couple suggestions:

1. Get a user that is not saved in the database:

   user = Factory.build(:user)

Or,

1. use a before each block:

   before(:each) do
     @user = Factory(:user)
   end

   (then change the "user" variables to "@user")